# Sharing tables across multiple sites

Tags: python, mysql, galera

this is more of an **architecture question** which I can't solve this properly as I don't have enough experience with such architecture... I'm currently running the solution with **Python** and **SqlAlchemy**, but the question is generic and the answer doesn't have to address those technologies.

I will try to explain it on an example of public library. So imagine having a public library, with server holding tables with all the books, scans (large binary images), users. I've already made a client and server parts which work great, but locally for a single library.

Now I would like to have this of server and clients for another public library (and later more public libraries to come). Having a local server for each library is desired as there is much data to be transferred to and from local server.

The complication comes from the requirement to be able to share users (with their member cards) between libraries - if user comes and registers at library A, he should be able to go to library B without the need for new registration. There's no need for being able to see other user data in the library he wasn't registered in the first place, just hist member account (id, login and password).

The simple solution would be:

- having large data on local server
- having users on cloud (some public server on internet)

The problem is that there are queries (for statistics, views, and so on), which run on local server and need accessing users, so I can't have users on a different server and database, because I couldn't then do select + join on such an architecture.

The solution which is left behind by previous developer and which other developers think is wrong, is to have the users table set up as **replicated table** (**MariaDB + Galera**), so it would end up having users table the same on cloud and each library site, so the previous code would work as if everything is just local, while sharing the users on the background with other libraries.

One of the problems with this is that the current version of our database (MariaDB) doesn't support (or has broken) partial replication (only some tables or some databases), so it would need patching of the MariaDB and distributing this patched version of database server to cloud and other sites, which stinks of various problems now and in the future, when new version of MariaDB will come out.

What would be the proper way of sharing these users between sites, while retaining the ability to do local selects and joins with the user table?

(Maybe there's a known design / architecture pattern for this, but I just don't know what to search for as I'm new to this.)

Thanks, 
Miro

[schema - sharing table between sites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX8YA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Start with a single-source-of truth for the user registrations.  That is *one* server (or Galera cluster, for HA) somewhere (in HQ, in Cloud, wherever).  Login queries remotely access that server.

Think about any place you log in -- you are going to some central cite.  My point is, that is the way everyone does it because it is fast, reliable, efficient, etc, with today's networks.

Next, what about images, etc?  If they are shared across your sites, you may as well do them the same way.  Look at any search engine for the last two decades -- images (etc) are fetched from a single site.  (Actually a small number of sites, for redundancy, etc).  Even the biggest web providers have no more than perhaps a dozen datacenters to service the entire world.

After that, you need to decide on Cloud vs dedicated (or even run your own datacenter).

For HA, Cloud providers do a lot.  For do-it-yourself, there are various replication scenarios, Galera being one of the best (today).  For true HA, you need two copies of your data geographically separated -- to protect from hurricanes, fires, floods, earthquakes, etc.  Consider a WAN deployment of Galera, or some asynchronouse replication (possibly even between two Galera clusters.

Another choice is whether the Users and Images tables need to be on separate servers.  Only if the traffic and size are high do you need to consider separating them.  For a huge Image library, you may need a large number of servers, at which point, they should probably living on servers with the sole purpose of delivering images -- no Users, no HTML pages, etc.  Even the "meta" info about images could be elsewhere in MySQL; the Images are in files and just a web server tuned to deliver images runs.  (I can think of multiple 'big guys' that do it this way.)

Comment: Moving everything to central server would be one of the ways how to do it. The original solution (even with database replication) has 2 benefits opposed to central server:
- it would work even if internet is down, with connection to local server only
- it has all the other tables separate - each site (library instance) has each own records which it doesn't want to share with other sites (e.g. payments, and so on)

Comment: Syncing two "separate" masters is a mess.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answers (both long and short). From them I've at least got the idea how to do it, and I've learned things like SSoT and HA ;) 

One thing I would like to hear your opinion on is having those separate MariaDB (or MySQL) databases, replicated, but not using only one of them at the time as SSoT, but instead each site accessing its own, and relying on replication to handle the syncing. That sounds to me just like syncing separate masters. (This is the idea which is opposed by some of my colleagues.)

Comment: Writing to both heads of a "dual master" if fraught with pitfalls; avoid it.  (Galera solves them.)  With truly separate databases, "multi-source replication" may be viable.  But it may be tricky for your set up.  (I have not thought through the details.)  Is the network really that flaky?